# Selenium grid scalability issue

Tags: automated-tests, selenium-grid

I have Selenium Grid which can run 5 Chrome instances.
I have written Java code which sends commands to Selenium Grid to create new instance and then execute my tests. Selenium Grid is working fine. In some of the test I am creating an entity (say user). When user is successfully created, we show successful message for 2 seconds and close popup. When I run single test on grid then it is working fine. When i tried to run 5 testcases on Selenium Grid, then it seems its action switches between different browser instance. Sometimes it takes a lot of time and verification step fails. Is there any way I can handle this situation other than to use a different verification step. How can I run Selenium Grid faster.

Answer (score 1):

Running 5 browser sessions on the same machine is possible, but won't run well, unless the machine is well speced, and depending on the size of DOM and amount of javascript the page is using.  You could consider joining more machines to your grid, or increasing the CPU and RAM on your grid nodes.

Comment: Even with more machines it is possible(though less frequently) that my verification step may fail. It seems like there is no decent way to test successful message which disappeared after 2 seconds.